# Spring data source in JBoss EAP 6.1 fails with error "warning cant determine superclass of missing type org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrapperDataSource

Tags: jboss7.x, aspectj, spring-data, jboss-eap-6

We are upgrading JBoss from 5 to EAP 6.1

We are getting following error during deployment. Anyone faced similar issue?

```
Error creating bean with name xyzSessionFactory defined in class path resource [applicationContext-xyz-dao.xml]: 
Cannot resolve reference to bean xyzDataSource while setting bean property dataSource; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name xyzDataSource: Post-processing of the FactoryBeans object failed; 
nested exception is org.aspectj.weaver.reflect.ReflectionWorld$ReflectionWorldException: 
warning cant determine superclass of missing type org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrapperDataSource [Xlint:cantFindType]
        at com.mycompanyxyz.configuration.service.interceptor.SpringConfigurationInterceptor.autowireBean(SpringConfigurationInterceptor.java:60) [common-configuration-27.1.3-SNAPSHOT.jar:]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.6.0_38]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) [rt.jar:1.6.0_38]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) [rt.jar:1.6.0_38]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) [rt.jar:1.6.0_38]
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceLifecycleMethodInterceptorFactory$ManagedReferenceLifecycleMethodInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceLifecycleMethodInterceptorFactory.java:118) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.3.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.1.3.Final-redhat-4]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-2]
        at org.jboss.invocation.WeavedInterceptor.processInvocation(WeavedInterceptor.java:53) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-2]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-2]
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceInterceptorFactory$ManagedReferenceInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceInterceptorFactory.java:95) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.3.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.1.3.Final-redhat-4]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-2]
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceInterceptorFactory$ManagedReferenceInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceInterceptorFactory.java:95) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.3.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.1.3.Final-redhat-4]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-2]
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceInterceptorFactory$ManagedReferenceInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceInterceptorFactory.java:95) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.3.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.1.3.Final-redhat-4]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-2]
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceInterceptorFactory$ManagedReferenceInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceInterceptorFactory.java:95) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.3.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.1.3.Final-redhat-4]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-2]
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceInterceptorFactory$ManagedReferenceInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceInterceptorFactory.java:95) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.3.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.1.3.Final-redhat-4]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-2]
        at org.jboss.invocation.WeavedInterceptor.processInvocation(WeavedInterceptor.java:53) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-2]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-2]
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.3.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.1.3.Final-redhat-4]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-2]
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:41) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.3.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.1.3.Final-redhat-4]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-2]
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.TCCLInterceptor.processInvocation(TCCLInterceptor.java:45) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.3.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.1.3.Final-redhat-4]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-2]
        at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-2]
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.BasicComponent.constructComponentInstance(BasicComponent.java:161) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.3.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.1.3.Final-redhat-4]
        ... 104 more
```

The following link gives some clue that it seems to be an issue with AspectJ.

http://issues.liferay.com/browse/LPS-23012

http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?109227-AspectJ-Problem-warning-can-t-determine-superclass-of-missing-type-Proxy28

Comment: Is there additional information you can share that makes you think it's got to do with Spring Data? I don't see anything related to it in the stack trace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue resolved when we upgrade our JBoss EAP from 6.0.1 to 6.1